# Laravel chain Eloquent models

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

How can I turn this Eloquent chain

```
User::find(Sentry::getUser()->id)
    ->friends()
    ->join('users', 'friends.friend_id', '=', 'users.id')
    ->get();
```

into something like

```
User::find(Sentry::getUser()->id)
       ->friends()
       ->user()
       ->get();
```

There is a `User` model and a `Friends` model. The goal here is to get all friends of the current User and attach each the respective User model to each Friend. The `User` model has a `hasMany('Friends')` relationship on it.

What I have works I would just like to simplify the call if possible into something cleaner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have your relations correctly set, you can just

```
User::with('friends')->where('id', Sentry::getUser()->id)->get();
```

Comment: Make sure you are using singular and plural for the relationship correctly.